# How to convert digits in format "hhmmss" to time format hh:mm:ss using javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, time, time-format

I have string like `080000` and i want to change it to time format like `08:00:00` (like date format of type string) using javascript or jquery. How can i do this work?

Comment: I think the string should be `080000` because hour can be double digits.

Comment: Yes..But how to acheive the solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily split string to two-digit numbers using regex in [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) that return values in array. Then use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to joins items of array into string.

```js
var str = "080000";
str = str.match(/\d{2}/g).join(":");
console.log(str);
```